# how to find a feature map

Tags: feature-selection, kernel-trick

I have a dataset and it's 2 concentric circles centered at 0 of radius 1 and 2 corresponding to the two different classes. It's easy to seperate the data to get a classifier with 100% accuracy (I'm thinking for example, $x^2+y^2=1.5^2$) , however, how can I write down a feature map $\phi:R^2 \rightarrow R$, such that the transformed data $\phi(x)$ is linearly separable?

Comment: Hint: Can you write $x^2 + y^2 = 1.5^2$ as the desired feature map? Does this kernel have a name?